# What determines the number of TCP packets in boost::asio?

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, boost-asio, packet

I am sending TCP packets via `asio::tcp::socket`.

My problem is that although each time the data I send is about **800 bytes** and the maximum packet size is **1500 bytes** the data is sent in over 5 packets.

(I check the number of packets and the data in sniffsmart software)

why is that?!

how should I solve or track this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** : Number of packets in a streaming protocol like TCP depends on your network configurations. However this answer optimizes the use of sockets so that no overhead is added by the program in sense of number of transmitted packets.

If you are trying to get larger packets you should try to put all data on socket at once. You probably are dividing it to multiple packets yourself. Because of [Nagle's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) algorithm of TCP, TCP stack will send available data to peer immediately. So if you put data on socket in multiple occasions the rest of the data will go to the next packet.

Or you can turn off Nagle's algorithm like this :

```
m_socket.set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));
```

Comment: This will not guarantee 1500 packet length anyway.

Comment: my problem was that the data which has less a size than the maximum packet size was being sent in more than one packet,and in this case this answer fits.

Comment: While this answer is correct in one sense, TCP is still a stream based protocol, and you should _not_ relay on a 1-1 matching of `send()` to `recv()` calls.

Comment: @Chad You are right. I added an edit to clarify the purpose of this question.

Comment: @wiggily to turn off Nagle's Algorithm no_delay should be set to true

Comment: @Shohreh Fixed it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a stream. You cannot control what certain packets will contain. You can on/off Nagle algorithm, this can affect transfer speed, but you cannot control size of packets themself. More, these packets can be splitted/joined by any router on the way. So its stream by nature and you cannot change this.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a kind of stream data. send() only put data into send buffer, system TCP stack implementation decide how to put data onto network. That's reason why packets you saw via sniff doesn't match your send() calls. If you really want send packet to match send(), I remember there is a TCP option. You may check it, I cannot recall it exactly now.

Comment: the data I send is about 500 bytes ,800 bytes is the data size on the network,but it still sends more than one packet

Comment: It should resolve address and get physical address first, than establish TCP connection and so on. Connect is the most heavy operation in TCP. Are you measure this after connection is already established?